# Почему на сафари для disabled инпута стили сохраняются?

Tags: html, css

хоть и прописываю инпуту background-color: #fff

```css
input:disabled {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #e9e8f4;

}

input {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  appearance: none;
  color: red;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" disabled value="hgggwgwaga">
```

Comment: у меня отображается корректно. О какой версии сафари идет речь? Мобильная или десктопная?

Comment: @Grundy, Мобильная. Суть в том, что текст в инпуте немного  не четкий. будто дали прозрачность

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй сбросить стили для состояния disabled.

```
input:disabled {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #e9e8f4;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```